# Can we Implement Multiple Resolver in a single Service?

Tags: angular, routes, resolver

Since Resolver are implement on route level and we can also use more then one resolver on a single route 
But my question is that are we use different services for multiple resolver or it is possible with in a single service ?
** Apparently this is look not possible because we can implement only one method at a time **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use **ActivatedRoute** service if any component want to use any resolver it can subscribe any of them 
this can also done by **ActivatedRouteSnapshot**.